# How can I get function call information based on stack address in Windows

Tags: c++

Now, i have a machine that prints the stack memory address information of the log, but because the symbol address is not successfully resolved, I cannot know which function calls these memory address pairs correspond to, so I can’t analyze the cause of the problem.

```
1
0x00007fffb68438ed (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
2
0x00007fffb6848923 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
3
0x00007fffb6833005 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
4
0x00007fffb6df8e7e (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
5
0x00007fffb6df0d7c (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
6
0x00007fffb6df87a8 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
7
0x00007fffb6abfdc3 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
8
0x00007fffb61c46c4 (UnityPlayer)
9
0x00007fff68f9c0b5 (GameAssembly) BrotliDecoderIsFinished
10
0x00007fff68f9a1b1 (GameAssembly) BrotliDecoderIsFinished
11
0x00007fff68f99feb (GameAssembly) BrotliDecoderIsFinished
12
0x00007fff678b35ff (GameAssembly) il2cpp_class_get_static_field_data
13
0x00007fff67e2bc16 (GameAssembly) il2cpp_field_get_value_object
14
0x00007fff67e2bbb4 (GameAssembly) il2cpp_field_get_value_object
15
0x00007fffb6632f28 (UnityPlayer)
16
0x00007fffb6636152 (UnityPlayer)
17
0x00007fffb6c51166 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
18
0x00007fffb64b5e9a (UnityPlayer)
19
0x00007fffb64b5f40 (UnityPlayer)
20
0x00007fffb64b8c18 (UnityPlayer)
21
0x00007fffb66ad98a (UnityPlayer)
22
0x00007fffb66ac6bb (UnityPlayer)
23
0x00007fffb66b0e97 (UnityPlayer)
24
0x00007fffb66b29fb (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
25
0x00007ff83ae526ad (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
26
0x00007ff83bf4aa68 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Then What I want to ask first is, how can I restore the stack according to these memory addresses, so that I can clearly see the corresponding function calls, and I have related .pdb symbol files and executable files exe locally.